# Using multi threading for reading information

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, batch-processing

I have the next scenario:

1. the server send a lot of information from a Socket, so I need to read this information and validate it. The idea is to use 20 threads and batches, each time the batch size is 20, the thread must send the information to the database and keep reading from the socket waiting for more.

I don't know what it would be the best way to do this, I was thinking:

1. create a Socket that will read the information
2. Create a Executor (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)`) and validate de information, and add each line into a list and when the size is 20 execute the Runnable class that will send the information to the database.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that using multi-threads will do anything more than make your code more complicated.  Do you know you have a problem and that using more threads is the solution?  What measurements have you made?

Comment: The amount of rows send in a day could be 1 million so using multhread it would be easier, because is an online system, the faster the information gets the DB the better for the system.

Comment: One million rows per day is less than 11.6 rows per second on average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do this with a whole bunch of threads. You're better off using a producer-consumer model with just two threads.

The producer thread reads records from the socket and places them on a queue. That's all it does: read record, add to queue, read next record. Lather, rinse, repeat.

The consumer thread reads a record from the queue, validates it, and writes it to the database. If you want to batch the items so that you write 20 at a time to the database, then you can have the consumer add the record to a list and when the list gets to 20, do the database update.

You probably want to look up information on using the Java `BlockingQueue` in producer-consumer programs.

You said that you might get a million records a day from the socket. That's only 12 records per second. Unless your validation is hugely processor intensive, a single thread could probably handle 1,200 records per second with no problem.

In any case, your major bottleneck is going to be the database updates, which probably won't benefit from multiple threads.

Comment: The thing is the connections to the Database, because the system has a lot of connections, this is going to be one of the app that interact with the system, so I was thinking it could block the database.

Comment: I was checking BlockingQueue and it a good idea, but It came to my mind what would be the best implementation for this scenario, I was thinking about ArrayBlockingQueue, but I don't know if LinkedBlockingQueue is better. I need is to process the information really fast.

Comment: Also I need to have insert in two differents DB according to the validations, so I thinks is better to have 2 consumers instead of one (one for putting into each database)

Comment: @user1623801: You can still do that with a single consumer. Just have two different buffers to hold records. It's up to you, but you'll probably find it easier to write it with a single consumer first, and might be fast enough. If it's not, *then* split it into multiple consumers. Don't make it any more complicated than it has to be.